# Finding nearest value in a mysqli array php

Tags: php, sorting

In my app, the user can enter a number for pricing and based on the input, the database will return a plan with the same price. If there is no number/price corresponding to the user input, I would like the program to find the plan with the nearest value. How can I find the "nearest" value in a haystack?

```
Examples :
User inputs : $14, Returns the 15$ plan
User inputs : $20, Returns the 15$ plan
User inputs : 25$. Returns the 30$ plan
Etc...
```

This is what I have :

```
//Create pricing for each plan
$getplansql = "SELECT SUM(`Distributor Net Price`) AS dnetprice FROM `services` wspn
 WHERE wspn.planName = '$planname_num[$pn]' AND wspn.planLevel = '$planlevels_num[$pl]'";
 $resultplans = $conn->query($getplansql);

 while($plan = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultplans)) {// output data of each row

  $inhousepricing = ($plan['dnetprice'] * 0.15) + ($plan['dnetprice']);
   $finalpricing = round($inhousepricing);

     if($planprice == $finalpricing) {//found matching row// there's a plan with that price
      //put plan info in array            
                        $planArray = array(
                          'planName' => $plan['name'],
                          'planPrice' => $finalpricing,
                          'planDescription' => $plan['description']
                        );
    break;//stop statement and only get the first plan//row found

    }else{//get the plan with the nearest value

     //put plan info in array  
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 15% and find the closest price in the SQL query itself.

```
$getplansql = "name, description, dnetprice
               FROM (
                    SELECT planName AS name, planDescription AS description, ROUND(SUM(`Distributor Net Price`) * 1.15) AS dnetprice 
                    FROM `services` wspn
                    WHERE wspn.planName = '$planname_num[$pn]' AND wspn.planLevel = '$planlevels_num[$pl]'
                ) AS x
                ORDER BY ABS(dnetprice - $planprice)
                LIMIT 1";
$resultplans = $conn->query($getplansql);
$planArray = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultplans);
```

This will just return the one row that you want, so you don't need a `while` loop.

Comment: Yes it does need to be in the while loop. I will update my answer and show you the reason why.

Comment: If there are multiple rows with the closest price, do you need all of them?

Comment: No I just need one row.

Comment: Then why would you need a loop? It will just return 1 row, so you call `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` once to get it.

Comment: Ok you are right with the while loop, I will remove that. However, I can't do the comparison in the statement because the pricing is not in the table. I'm using SUM() to output the price by adding columns together then I'm adding 15% to come up with final pricing. I will update my answer for you to see the statement.

Comment: `ORDER BY` can refer to aliases in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: So if you're doing `SUM(itemPrice) * 1.15 AS planPrice` this will work.

Comment: Okay. I'm a visual learner. Mind updating your answer with what I have updated?

Comment: I've upated the answer. I had to make some modifications to add the `name` and `description` columns to the query

Comment: So out of curiosity why does 1.15 represent 15%? What would represent 25% or 30% for instance?

Comment: High school algebra. `x + y*x` is the same thing as `(1 + y) * x`.

Comment: 25% would be `1.25`

Comment: Makes sense. I've seen something like this (column * column_2 / 100 as decimal(15,4))

Comment: `.15` is `15%`, `1.15` is *adding* 15%

Comment: Your answer looks great on papers but after many tests it's not passing in my program. Mysql throws error 'dnetprice' not supported (reference to group function). I cant use it.

Comment: Ugh, it's a MySQL limitation, you can order by an alias, but you can't put the alias inside a more complex expression. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128504/creating-calculated-column for workarounds.

Comment: I've updated the answer to use one of the workarounds.

Comment: Very much so. Thanks Barmar.